# Net force equal to mass multiplied by acceleration of centre of mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration

$F=ma$ if $a=0$ then definitely the net force applied will be also zero (0).
then, in this case $m=F/a$.

If both net force and acceleration(of centre of mass) is equal to zero (0).
then, isn't mass must be equal to $m=0/0$ i.e. undefined?

in this question i am talking about suppose a block on which we apply a balanced force.i am not talking about gravitational force(mg) and gravitational acceleration?

Comment: You're trying to extrapolate information of the mass of an object when you have no information regarding force, and your acceleration is 0. i.e., you won't be able to find mass with that kind of information.

Comment: Division by zero is undefined and thus, dividing both sides of $F=ma$ by $a$ is valid for $a \ne 0$ but not for $a = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you measure a force (weight) for a given acceleration (gravity) in order to determine the mass of an object and you haven't started measuring then the mass is undefined. As soon as you apply an acceleration $a>0$ and you measure corresponding force $F>0$ you can *determine* the mass.

Equations are useful only when they can be used to measure things, and if the result is $\frac{0}{0}$ then that particular equation is not useful in this particular scenario.